# Android Studio Text to Speech.Need to browse File manager and then select .txt file to speech

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I know how to do TTS but need help in browsing file explorer and selecting a .txt file from anywhere in the sdcard and then push the text to textview. Below is my code.I can til now give specific file path and can only read from it. but need to make a file explorer to select .txt file.

```
   package com.example.shubham.tts;

/**
 * Created by shubham on 27/9/16.
 */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileOperations
{
    public FileOperations()
    {

    }

    public String read(String fname)
    {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String response = null;

        try
        {

            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            String fpath = "/sdcard/documents/"+fname;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fpath));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                output.append(line +"\n");
            }
            response = output.toString();

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to provide path of your text file and get all string from .txt file and put it in    t1.speak(yourtext, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

Comment: please don't downvote as user is new and wants help and android doesn't provide any built in method for reading .txt in TTs framework

Comment: Can't ask more question because this question too much downgraded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to extract txt from your file ,if your file is on sd card

```
   File exStrg= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

//Get the text file

```
   File file = new File(exStrg,"file.txt");
```

//Read text from file

```
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    text.append(line);
    text.append('\n');
}
br.close();
  }
catch (IOException e) {

//error handling here
```

}

Now   get all string from .txt file and put it in

```
      ttsInstance.speak(yourtext, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Let me know if it helped

Comment: Actually I want to make browse button in the app then using it select some random file from file explorer and read it. Till now I can read files from a very specific path only given in code and then type the files name in the code.But I want to select .txt file from anywhere on the device. Thanks for the help. Need a litte bit more.

Comment: @DhruvNunia Thanks you can accept the answer if it helped by pressing accept button and upvoting it.You will need to explore I/O of  devices lil more. give it a try we are alwys for help